# Firebase Cloud Messaging Images not showing

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I searched but I couldn't find any related issues. We are sending bulk notifications (around 30k users), and they are being delivered, but the images/icons are not being shown. When we test the same message with only a few users, everything works ok. We tried breaking the list into batches of ~500 users but the results are the same.
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending these notifications? Are you sending them through Firebase Notification Campaign in the Firebase Console?